# How can I change date format for formGroups input element with Angular 7?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-date-format

When input is of type 'Date', date format is `dd/MM/yyyy`.
I want to change date format from `MM/dd/yyyy` to `dd/MM/yyyy` (Turkish Format and Turkish Calender).

Here is the code.

```
<form [formGroup]="opportunityForm" (ngSubmit)="updateData(opportunityForm.value)">
 <div class="form-group">
          <label>Oluşturulma Tarihi</label>
          <input  type="date"  class="form-control"  formControlName="createDate" required>
          <div class="alert-danger" *ngIf="!opportunityForm.controls['createDate'].valid && (opportunityForm.controls['createDate'].touched)">
            <div [hidden]="!opportunityForm.controls['createDate'].errors.required">
              Tarih alanı gerekli
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!opportunityForm.valid">Güncelle</button>
</form>



constructor(private http: HttpClient,private fb: FormBuilder,private router: Router,private actRoute: ActivatedRoute, private service:OpportunityService) {
    this.opportunityForm=this.fb.group({
      title:['',Validators.required],
      description:['',Validators.required],
      createDate:['',Validators.required],
      expirationDate:['',Validators.required],
      file: new FormControl(null)  
    });
```

Suggestions and solutions will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to  just send date in turkish format to backend?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can manipulate your formControl field 'createDate'.

Use DatePipe provided by angular to change date in any desired format.

Firstly,import DatePipe in your component's ts:

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
```

Inject date pipe in providers array:

```
styleUrls: ['component.css'];
providers: [DatePipe] // like this you inject pipe,services
```

Declare in constructor :

```
 constructor(
    private datePipe: DatePipe
  ) { }
```

You can either make a function which manipulate date; simply call in `updateData(formValue)` or directly manipulate date in `updateData(formValue)` method

// date manipulation using DatePipe

```
const datePipe = this.datePipe.transform(this.opportunityForm.get('createDate').value, 'dd-MM-yyyy')
```

Comment: I tried the code which you texted, this code provides to save date to database.Thanks for this.But I also want to get same thing from user/form . How can I do ? Is it possible ?

Comment: You can initialize your formgroup to do it.

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple way to do this, But can you explain if you want to change the format looks even in the html? if not i'd suggest you to use `formatDate` instead of `datePipe` which is lot easier in my opinion.

in your .ts file do this.

```
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';
 this.opportunityForm.value.createDate = formatDate(this.opportunityForm.value.createDate, 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'en');
 // 'yyyy/MM/dd' format can be replaced with however you want to
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved this issue using DatePipe for making format which I wanted at the backend side.
And also I change language of browser.Thus,user can see date format that user wants.

Comment: For calendar, setting language and shifting it to the top (making default language) in browser setting.